# Generate a maze by fusing the cell's values

Tags: c

I have to generate a maze for a school project, but I'm stuck in a loop, I have no idea why, and my IDE ignores my breakpoints for some reason...

Here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 



typedef struct _maze_cell {
    int wallAbove, wallLeft, cellValue;
} MazeCell;

/* define maze structure */
typedef struct _maze_t {
    /* maze size = m lines * n columns */
    int row, column;
    /* array of cells */
    MazeCell* *array;
} Maze;



MazeCell* initMazeCell(){
    MazeCell* cell = malloc(sizeof(MazeCell));
    cell->wallAbove = 1;
    cell->wallLeft = 1;
    cell->cellValue = 0;
    return cell;

}

int rand_a_b(int a, int b){    

    return rand()%(b-a) +a;

}

Maze* initMaze(int m, int n)
 {
  Maze* oMaze= malloc(sizeof(Maze));
  int nbCells=m*n;
  printf("%d \n", nbCells);
  oMaze->array = malloc(nbCells*sizeof(MazeCell));

   int counter=1;
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<m*n;i++)
    {
         if(i%m==0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        oMaze->array[i]= initMazeCell();
        oMaze->array[i]->cellValue=counter++;


        printf("%4d", oMaze->array[i]->cellValue);
    }

      printf("\n");
    //------------------------loop debut
    int done=0;
    while(done==0)
    {
        done=1;
        int sizeofTab=m*n-1;
        int nbAl=rand_a_b( 0, sizeofTab);
        int wallChoosen=rand_a_b( 1, 2);

        if(wallChoosen==1)
        {
            if(nbAl>n)
          {
              int b=nbAl-n;
              int oldValue=oMaze->array[b]->cellValue;
              int newValue=oMaze->array[nbAl]->cellValue;

              if(oldValue!=newValue)
                {
                    oMaze->array[nbAl]->wallAbove=0;
                    for(i=0;i<m*n;i++)
                    {
                        if(oMaze->array[i]->cellValue==oldValue)
                        {
                            //printf("old: %d",oMaze->array[i]->cellValue);
                            oMaze->array[i]->cellValue=newValue;
                            // printf("new: %d",oMaze->array[i]->cellValue);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    if(wallChoosen==2)
     {
        if(nbAl>0)
         {
            int b=nbAl-1;
            int oldValue=oMaze->array[b]->cellValue;
            int newValue=oMaze->array[nbAl]->cellValue;


            if(oldValue!=newValue)
            {
                oMaze->array[nbAl]->wallLeft=0;
                for(i=0;i<m*n;i++)
                {
                    if(oMaze->array[i]->cellValue==oldValue)
                    {
                        oMaze->array[i]->cellValue=newValue;
                    }

                }
            //oMaze->array[b]->cellValue=oMaze->array[nbAl]->cellValue;

            }
        }
    }
      int a;
      for(i=0;i<m*n;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                a=oMaze->array[i]->cellValue;
            }
            if(i!=0 && oMaze->array[i]->cellValue!=a)
            {
                done=0;
                printf("%4d", oMaze->array[i]->cellValue);
            }

        }

    }
    //--------------------------------loop end
    printf("\n The end!!");
    int y;
    for(y=0;y<m*n;y++)
    {
         if(y%m==0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%4d", oMaze->array[y]->cellValue);
    }
    return oMaze;
 }

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Maze* myMaze=initMaze(5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

The teacher told us to use this method :[maze generation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A9lisation_math%C3%A9matique_d%27un_labyrinthe#Fusion_al%C3%A9atoire_de_chemins)(sorry it's in french, but the image will help understand my what I'm trying to do in my code).

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

I added a counter and stopped the loop after 200 turn and I get this:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwWWz.png)

This shows that it works until a certain point, I don't know why it doesn't work until the end...

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` must be called only once at the beginning of your program, not every time you generate a random number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Comment: Thanks, I put it in the main but I'm still facing the same problem, did I put it in the wrong place again?, when I print the random value it does change for each loop.

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine `M_PI`?  That makes no sense.  If you really need the constant 314 for some incomprehensible reason, then give it a different name.  But preferably just delete that line.

Comment: I deleted it, I had forgotten to delete it after trying another method thanks, but I'm still stuck in the while loop...

Comment: [Maze Generation (english)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) provides a C-example that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong:

```
`int wallChoosen=rand_a_b( 1, 2);`
```

I thought it was from 1 to 2, 2 included, but 2 is not included, so wallChoosen was always equal to 1.

I replaced it with:

`int wallChoosen=rand_a_b( 1, 3);`